# Javascript framework for File Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, file-upload

I have a location on server hosted by node.js /public/imagedepot which contains subfolders and image files. I want to create an admin page which can select the selective images or complete subfolder from the imagedepot from the filebrowser on the html page and then on submit the array with the location of the images selected can be posted to the server.

For this purpose, is there any library or extension in the javascript present which can provide me with the gui of the folder and file picker in the tree format and can have multi select which  then returns the array with the selected images and their paths.

This would be easy if an open source framework is available.

I am using expressjs node.js and javascript

I dont want to upload the file to the server only the user can select the name of images from the browser and then it provides a array with the selected filename and path.

Comment: Just to clarify: Are the files you want to select with the file picker on the client machine or on the server?

Comment: The files are located on the server and i will provide the file (files and folders) form expressjs response.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most file pickers are going to want to select from files on the client machine. To allow the client to select a file on the server I would populate a list of file choices on the server side. This should get you started: [How do you get a list of the names of all files present in a directory in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727167/getting-all-filenames-in-a-directory-with-node-js)

Next I would display the choices to the user like this example:
[Expandable Tree Menu List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506118/expandable-tree-menu-list)

Comment: I actually dont want to upload the files just want to populate the file structure of the server side on the tree type expanding structure such that admin can select the multiple files using checkbox for e.g. Sorry if my question was unclear

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend CKFinder. Whether you already have the images on the server or they should be uploaded, that would be the best fit. http://cksource.com/ckfinder

Moreover, you can integrate their HTML WYSWYG editor (CKEditor) with it.